# Creating an RTF file with PHP

Tags: php, file, text, ms-office, rtf

So far I've done the following:

```
$file_p = fopen('blabla.rtf', 'w');
fwrite($file_p, 'something');
fclose($file_p);
```

Which creates a file with a .rtf extension but when I open it with notepad I don't see the rtf tags, why is that and how could I create a **real** .rtf file?

Comment: Not really, i'm looking for a way to do this in PHP natively without any external library.

Comment: You only see what you write to the file, which is `something`. If you want there to be something else, you need to write that instead. Fill your boots: https://web.archive.org/web/20190708132914/http://www.kleinlercher.at/tools/Windows_Protocols/Word2007RTFSpec9.pdf

Comment: If you know RTF specification well, you can try, however I'm afraid that putting simple text and giving it _*.rtf_ file extension isn't a solution.